# Unity Examples with AWS Cognito and S3 for posting files

Tags: unity-game-engine, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I am trying to run the example Unity packages provided by Amazon to post a file to my bucket, which is the us-west-1 region. The message back says its successful, but there's no file. When I put the http response in Debug.Log, it says Moved (which I assume is 301). When I've researched this it says there could be a region error, but I know its the right region (us-west-1 for Northern California).

Here are my Inspector, IAM policy and bucket policies.

[image: Unity Inspector config]

[image: IAM Policy]

[image: Buckey Policy]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It seems there may be a bug in the code provided by Amazon. When I created bucket in the US Standard region and specified us-east-1, everything worked fine.